# BASH - Delete specific lines

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I need to remove every line that has value like `SUPMA` in the 4th column.

My data looks like this:

```
abc;def;ghi;SUPMA;klm
abc;def;ghi;SUPMA;klm
SUPMA;def;ghi;MA;klm
abc;def;ghi;SUPMA;klm
abc;def;ghi;SUP;klm
```

In this example, I want to keep the 3th and 5th lines.

How can i do this in bash script? Can i use AWK?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, and yes. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F";" '$4!="SUPMA"' yourfile.txt
```

Here awk splits the records by semicolon, then tests the 4th position for `SUPMA`. By default, if that condition passes, it will print the line.

Comment: Updated so the semicolon is in it's happy place.

Comment: Thank you. In reality 'SUPMA' value is in a variable. So, can I use your command with a variable?

Comment: To use a bash variable in your awk, you'll have to pass it in using the `-v` flag:  `awk -F";" -v awkvar=$bashvar '$4!=awkvar'`

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk -F\; '$4 !~/SUPMA/' file 
    SUPMA;def;ghi;MA;klm
    abc;def;ghi;SUP;klm
```